# AWS ELB cannot be attached to multiple subnets while it's not configured for it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, aws-vpc

I'm experiencing an issue with **AWS EB** today.

I'm trying to put an EC2 instance on 1 subnet (private) and the ELB on another one (public).

Then since this morning, I get this error while deploying:
Updating load balancer named: awseb-e-u-AWSEBLoa-1FULBEU6PSYPB failed Reason: **ELB cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same AZ**.

I don't understand, only one subnet is selected on my last try.

Here is the configuration

[image: EB Configuration]

Thanks

Comment: Speculation: it adds the new one before removing the old one, preventing you from doing what you want.  If true, the select a subnet in B, deselect A, apply, then go back and deselect B and select the subnet you really want in A, then apply again.